# can I use confint in R to get 95% CI using binomial exact method?

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I know confint in R can give 95% CI for one or more parameters in a fitted model object, but it seems the method types available in confint doesn't include binomial exact. How can I get the binomial exact CI by just giving the object? Below is an example:

```
fit <- lm(100/mpg ~ disp + hp + wt + am, data = mtcars)
confint(fit)
confint(fit, "wt")
```

Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure what you actually need.. the exact binomial confidence interval cannot be calculated using the standard errors from a linear regression

Comment: for a given p, n and you can construct the exact binomial confidence interval, but how would you get that from a linear regression? you can take a look at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/binom/binom.pdf